# Why does this prime-checker work?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code correctly determines if a number is prime:

```
var num = parseInt(prompt("Number:"));
var ans = "prime";

for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  if (num % i === 0) {
    ans = "not prime";
    break;
  }
}
alert(ans);
```

**Why does this code work for an input of "2"?**

I thought that an input of 2 would give "not prime", as 2%2===0 would be true.

Comment: Want to be a horrible student. Go and tell your teacher that the double mersenne prime number `170141183460469231731687303715884105727` is incorrectly categorized as not a prime by their code.

Comment: That would be fun, but i probably won't do that

Comment: No don't :D But you might get extra credit by explaining *why* that happens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought that an input of 2 would give "not prime", as 2%2===0 would be true.

`2 % 2` never happens.

The loop that checks for evenly divisible numbers is:

```
for (var i = 2; i < num;...
```

`i` starts at `2`, and `num` is the user input.

If `num` is *also* `2`, then the first test of `i < num` is `2 < 2`, which is false. The loop never executes and `ans` remains "prime".

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense... Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

The magic seems to be in the loop condition:

```
for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
```

If you input 2, the condition `i<num` is not met, so the body is not executed.

But. If you use 1 as your value, it will also return 'prime'. Or if you enter 0. Or negative values. It might be better to explicitly decide, if the given number is prime or not, not just by checking a certain set of numbers - or at least do some input validation.

Of course, if the main exercise is just to get some exercise with loops, his code is okay.

HTH
jesterchen

Comment: Input validation was not focused on as a part of this exercise, but that would definitely be needed otherwise